# How to do a PUT or DELETE for Azure Table Storage in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

So I've been working on a project where I want to build out basic CRUD like functionality for Azure Table Storage however I keep getting stuck on generating a valid SharedKeyLite signature.

I am able to generate a valid signature for GET and POST but when I want to PUT or DELETE and entity for some bizarre reason the signature is now invalid?

```
const axios = require('axios');

const client = axios.create({});

const SharedKeyGenerate = require('./SharedKeyGenerator');

const AZURE_STORAGE_KEY = 'STORAGE_KEY';
const AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT = 'igdevharuntest';

const sharedKey = new SharedKeyGenerate(AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT, 'powerbiTableStorage', AZURE_STORAGE_KEY);

client.defaults.baseURL = `https://${AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.table.core.windows.net`;
client.defaults.timeout = 2000;

/**
 * get tables from azure table storage
 * with optional filter
 * @param {string} path uri path
 * @param {string} filter filter for the web request
 */
async function getTables(path, filter) {
    try {
        const response = await client.get(`/${path}${filter}`, {
            headers: {
                'x-ms-date': new Date().toUTCString(),
                'Authorization': sharedKey.GenerateSharedKeyLite(path, 'GET', client),
                Accept: 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                'x-ms-version': '2015-12-11',
            }
        });

        console.log(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
    }
}

async function addEntityToTable(tableName) {
    const payload = {
        'expiresOn': '2019-10-16T17:27:36.046Z',
        'accessToken': 'abcsd123456',
        'PartitionKey': 'NewPartitionKey12',
        'RowKey': 'CompletelyNewKey12'
    };


    try {
        const response = await client.post(`/${tableName}`, payload,{
            headers: {
                'x-ms-date': new Date().toUTCString(),
                'Authorization': sharedKey.GenerateSharedKeyLite(tableName, "POST"),
                Accept: 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                'x-ms-version': '2015-12-11',
            }
        });

        console.log(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response);
    }
}

async function updateEntity(path, filter) {
    const payload = {
        "PartitionKey": "ABCDEFG1234567RANDOMPARTITIONKEY1111",
        "RowKey": "ABCDEFG1234567",
        "expiresOn": "2019-10-16T17:37:07.099Z",
        "accessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCjjJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImFQY3R3X29kdlJPb0VOZzNWb09sSWgydGlFcyIsImtpZCI6ImFQY3R3X29kdlJPb0VOZzNWb09sSWgydGlFcyJ9.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.prKqNPn75_CWdbLvsl5VVvuZAK-PEI2n1DlU4gFayt_eLPzllZUlEpVqIgVgTAzeccYEj5Z6vBKpMjXT7ftwCVjnKQitidGILehaEfrWiXX3xU4ZatPQ_TNc6Y6NzMyIQTWAbPkCHfpFnBlbAD0xp9Kl-bpAq_QXbl4yIa6_IQMRMwi5WdWd8WJLLdxKQTkWiKkGBBl-La3wgYrWfzBXMzBLhlfMk_vqsOyJdg1jOUEnUmScqxKh5DUR5DvoRtdeVxc2rDz1GWM8MTdhviB0CRub7bKeMA35rLzEui69L4o8gT_FuXLXqvVLDL9sq7OZNX8q3BL-VxLkq6GSOpnkcg"
    };


    try {
        const response = await client.put(`/${path}${filter}`, payload,{
            headers: {
                'x-ms-date': new Date().toUTCString(),
                'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8',
                'Authorization': sharedKey.GenerateSharedKeyLite(path, "PUT"),
                Accept: 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                'x-ms-version': '2015-12-11',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'If-Match': '*'
            }
        });

        console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
    }
}

async function deleteEntity(path, filter, partitionKey, rowKey) {
    try {
        const response = await client.delete(`/${path}${filter}`, {
            headers: {
                'x-ms-date': new Date().toUTCString(),
                'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8',
                'Authorization': sharedKey.GenerateSharedKeyLite(path),
                Accept: 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                'x-ms-version': '2015-12-11',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'If-Match': '*'
            }
        });

        console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
    }
}

//Works
getTables("powerbiTableStorage()", "?$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'ABCDEFG1234567RANDOMPARTITIONKEY1111'%20and%20RowKey%20eq%20'ABCDEFG1234567'");


//Works
addEntityToTable('powerbiTableStorage()');


//does not work
updateEntity("powerbiTableStorage(PartitionKey='ABCDEFG1234567RANDOMPARTITIONKEY1111',RowKey='ABCDEFG1234567')", "?$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'ABCDEFG1234567RANDOMPARTITIONKEY1111'%20and%20RowKey%20eq%20'ABCDEFG1234567'");


//does not work
deleteEntity("powerbiTableStorage(PartitionKey='ABCDEFG1234567RANDOMPARTITIONKEY1111',RowKey='ABCDEFG1234567')", "");
```

Here is the error message:
{
  'odata.error': {
    code: 'AuthenticationFailed',
    message: {
      lang: 'en-US',
      value: 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\n' +
        'RequestId:d5684fff-8002-001c-0dd9-9fe2c5000000\n' +
        'Time:2019-11-20T19:31:28.7740552Z'
    }
  }
}

Can someone help me out here?

A quick update...

here is what I get when I run a GET request

stringToSign:
Thu, 21 Nov 2019 15:48:07 GMT
/igdevharuntest/Tables

Signature:
SharedKeyLite igdevharuntest:PxpjkL+WwN7ZtHD1NXctjtMKSdWuAjNY3xS3jo7/n/Q=

```
{
  value: [
    { TableName: 'photowallCache' },
    { TableName: 'powerbiTableStorage' },
    { TableName: 'tblProjectStatus' }
  ]
}
```

Shared Key Generate:

```
const Utf8 = require('crypto-js/enc-utf8');
const Base64 = require('crypto-js/enc-base64');
const hmacSHA256 = require('crypto-js/hmac-sha256');



class SharedKeyGenerator {
    constructor(storageAccount, tableName, storageKey) {

        this.storageAccountName = storageAccount;
        this.storageAccountKey = storageKey;
        this.tableName = tableName;

    }


    /**
     * generates a shared key lite for authorization
     *
     * @param path path of the resource
     * @returns {string} signed signature
     */
    GenerateSharedKeyLite(path) {
        const date = new Date().toUTCString();

        let stringToSign = date + '\n' + this._getCanonicalizedResource(path);
        const hash = hmacSHA256(Utf8.parse(stringToSign), Base64.parse(this.storageAccountKey));
        const signature = Base64.stringify(hash);

        console.log(stringToSign);
        console.log('SharedKeyLite ' + this.storageAccountName + ':' + signature);
        return 'SharedKeyLite ' + this.storageAccountName + ':' + signature;
    }

    _getCanonicalizedResource(path) {
        return `/${this.storageAccountName}/${path}`;
    }
}

module.exports = SharedKeyGenerator;
```

Here is what I get when I do a PUT request

stringToSign:
Thu, 21 Nov 2019 15:48:07 GMT
/igdevharuntest/powerbiTableStorage(PartitionKey=NewPartitionKey12,RowKey=CompletelyNewKey12)

Signature:
SharedKeyLite igdevharuntest:dt14aw/McZet9JDiZDxnrZnwfMm8AfZZ7jNnTjVJ71A=

```
{
  'odata.error': {
    code: 'AuthenticationFailed',
    message: {
      lang: 'en-US',
      value: 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\n' +
        'RequestId:a9f6868a-c002-001b-6c83-a01440000000\n' +
        'Time:2019-11-21T15:48:07.3247287Z'
    }
  }
}
```

---- UPDATE -----

So I noticed that when I do a GET with my PartitionKey and RowKey values in parentheses I get an AuthenticationFailed error.

Ex: 
uri = GET:https://{azure_storage_account}.table.core.windows.net/TableStorageName(PartitionKey='PartitionKey',RowKey='RowKey')

Response is

```
{
  'odata.error': {
    code: 'AuthenticationFailed',
    message: {
      lang: 'en-US',
      value: 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\n' +
        'RequestId:a9f6868a-c002-001b-6c83-a01440000000\n' +
        'Time:2019-11-21T15:48:07.3247287Z'
    }
  }
}
```

If I keep the parentheses empty but add a filter as a query parameter this works just fine and I get the specific entity for my table.

Ex: 
GET:https://{azure_storage_account}.table.core.windows.net/TableStorageNam()?$filter=PartitionKey eq 'PartitionKey' and RowKey eq 'RowKey'

Response is:

```
{
  value: [
    {
      PartitionKey: 'PartitionKey',
      RowKey: 'RowKey',
      Timestamp: '2019-11-20T18:16:24.5881171Z',
      expiresOn: '2019-10-16T17:27:36.046Z',
      accessToken: 'abcsd123456'
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm thinking the way I'm building the canonicalized resource may be incorrect for values inside the parentheses? I have no clue.. I'm stuck now. All my header values are correct so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: note I removed the second parameter for GenerateSharedKeyLite.. does not do anythiing..

Comment: Can you edit your question and include code for `_getCanonicalizedResource` method? Also, please include the detailed error message.

Comment: @GauravMantri done, I've updated the question

Comment: @GauravMantri Any insight into my updates? I still get an error message when I used my signed signature against PUT requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

this is due to missing a **white-space** between partitionKey and RowKey when call update / delete function.

when call the delete function, should change

```
`deleteEntity("powerbiTableStorage(PartitionKey='ABCDEFG1234567RANDOMPARTITIONKEY1111',RowKey='ABCDEFG1234567')", "");`
```

to

```
`deleteEntity("powerbiTableStorage(PartitionKey='ABCDEFG1234567RANDOMPARTITIONKEY1111', RowKey='ABCDEFG1234567')", "");`
```

when call the update function, should change

```
updateEntity("powerbiTableStorage(PartitionKey='ABCDEFG1234567RANDOMPARTITIONKEY1111',RowKey='ABCDEFG1234567')", "?$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'ABCDEFG1234567RANDOMPARTITIONKEY1111'%20and%20RowKey%20eq%20'ABCDEFG1234567'");
```

to

```
updateEntity("powerbiTableStorage(PartitionKey='ABCDEFG1234567RANDOMPARTITIONKEY1111', RowKey='ABCDEFG1234567')", "");
```

---

For detele:

```
const request = require("request");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const url = require('url')

var accountName = "xxx";
var accountKey = "xxx";
var tableName = "test22";
var pk = "r1";
var rk = "s5";

const encodedUriPath = tableName + '(PartitionKey=' + '\'' + pk + '\'' + ', ' + 'RowKey=' + '\'' + rk + '\'' + ')';
console.log(encodedUriPath)
const endpoint = "https://" + accountName + ".table.core.windows.net/" + encodedUriPath;
const parsedUrl = url.parse(endpoint);
const timestamp = (new Date()).toUTCString();

console.log(url);
console.log(timestamp);
const stringToSign = timestamp + '\n/' +  accountName + parsedUrl.path;
console.log('--------------------------------------');
console.log(stringToSign);

const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', new Buffer(accountKey, 'base64'))
                  .update(stringToSign, 'utf-8')
                  .digest('base64');
console.log('--------------------------------------');
console.log(hmac);             

request.delete({
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'SharedKeyLite ' + accountName + ':' + hmac,
    'x-ms-date': timestamp,
    'x-ms-version': '2016-05-31',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'If-Match': '*'
  },
  'url': endpoint,
  'json': true
  }, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('inside delete err', JSON.stringify(err));

  } else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  }
});
```

The test result:

[image]

---

For [Update Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2) and [Delete Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-entity1) rest api, the header `If-Match` is required(refer to [Request Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-entity1#request-headers)). Otherwise, it will throw the error "AuthenticationFailed, xxxx".

In your `updateEntity` method, add `'If-Match': '*'` in the **headers** section, eg:

```
const response = await client.put(`/${tableName}(PartitionKey='${partitionKey}', RowKey='${rowKey}')`, payload,{
            headers: {
                'x-ms-date': new Date().toUTCString(),
                'Authorization': sharedKey.GenerateSharedKeyLite(tableName),
                Accept: 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                'x-ms-version': '2015-12-11',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'If-Match': '*'
            }
```

Comment: So I made sure that I had the If-Match header for update and I still get AuthenticationFailed. There is something wrong with my signature.. because microsoft returns an error saying I have a missing header field if its there unless im wrong...

Anyway this did not work for me.

Comment: @ibnawfi, I just tried it with delete operation, it worked. I will try to do the update operation later.

Comment: @ibnawfi, it's just a delete operation, if you need it, I'll post it.

Comment: Well I tried the delete operation and that's not working for me either.. I also need the PUT operation ..

Comment: @ibnawfi, ok, I will update my post with the delete operation first in a few minutes. and can you please post your completed code(and the packages you're using) for update / delete? So I can follow your code to test.

Comment: @ibnawfi, just update with the delete operation, you can take a look.

Comment: I figured it out following your instructions on the DELETE operation! Works for both PUT and DELETE!! Thank you soo much

Comment: and cannot believe just need a whitespace between the 2 keys.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that your request is working for `GET` and `POST` requests but not with `PUT` and `DELETE` ones. I believe you will need to include `(PartitionKey='${partitionKey}', RowKey='${rowKey}')` where you're computing `stringToSign` as this is part of URI.

```
GenerateSharedKeyLite(tableName, partitionKey, rowKey) {
    const date = new Date().toUTCString();
    let stringToSign = date + '\n' + this._getCanonicalizedResource() + '/' + tableName + '(PartitionKey=' + partitionKey + ', RowKey=' + rowKey + ')';
    const hash = hmacSHA256(Utf8.parse(stringToSign), Base64.parse(this.storageAccountKey));
    const signature = Base64.stringify(hash);


    console.log(stringToSign);
    // console.log returns this /igdevharuntest/powerbiTableStorage


    return'SharedKeyLite ' + this.storageAccountName + ':' + signature;
}
```

Please give it a try.

Comment: Hmmm...That's weird. Are you still getting 403 error? Can you please edit your question and add your updated code at the bottom of your post.

Comment: Hey I've added the update.. all I added was this:

        let stringToSign = date + '\n' + this._getCanonicalizedResource() + '/' + tableName + '(PartitionKey=' + partitionKey + ',RowKey=' + rowKey + ')';

When I go to update the entity, i get a 403

Comment: I noticed that you're passing completely new PartitionKey and RowKey in your request body. Are you trying to change those values through update operation?

Comment: Yes, I am but if that's not required then I can remove it I was just testing if I can update all fields

Comment: You can’t change these two properties but you’ll need to include them with original values in the request body. Can you please try by making this change?

Comment: Yeah I made sure I changed it so that my code is no longer updating the row key and partitionkey. Mu auth header is invalid im not sure why? I followed the documentation and it works with my GET and POST requests.. i'm really confused.